# Chart animation to start on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts

I'm looking for a way to start donut chart animation on scroll only, because at its current state, the chart animation starts whenever the page is loaded, and I can't see the animation happenening if the section is below other sections.

The chart was made with:  https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

The code: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/GEwMGP

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.chart-blue').easyPieChart({
    barColor: '#30bae7',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0,
    onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
      $(this.el).find('span').text(Math.round(percent));
    }
  });

  $('.chart-pink').easyPieChart({
    barColor: '#d74680',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0,
    onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
      $(this.el).find('span').text(Math.round(percent));
    }

  });

  $('.chart-green').easyPieChart({
    barColor: '#17c2a4',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0,
    onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
      $(this.el).find('span').text(Math.round(percent));
    }

  });


  $('.chart-orange').easyPieChart({
    barColor: '#eb7d4b',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineCap: 'circle',
    size: 150,
    scaleLength: 0,
    onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
      $(this.el).find('span').text(Math.round(percent));
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check out that [codepen](https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/VWOBMp?editors=1010)

Basically I wrote a If statement

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
```

that gets triggered when you scroll a specific amount of pixels (in this case 500) when this happened your charts will start to load and get the effect you wished for. Hope thats it if not leave a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your provided solution almost does the job for me, but the problem is, that the chart section in the actual template is 4th from the top, and the other thing is, for e.g, if you scroll down to the chart section, and then reload the page there, the page will open with the chart section being the first thing you see, and then the animation doesn't occur at all if you don't scroll a little bit.

Comment: maybe you should write that right from the beginning? I mean how are we supposed to know that? The Solution I wrote is exactly what you asked for in your Question. Increase the scrollValue so it matches your site and to the reloading problem: when this site is supposed to represent YOUR skills you should face the problem and solve it by yourself. I can find something for sure but maybe you should try to find a way ;-)

If you really can't think of a Solution, come back here and I will write one for you :)  @KestVir

Comment: @KestVir so how did it go? you achieved your goal? don't let answers stay like that.